# Divide string into parts w.r.t. area

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I want to create a PDF with some text.Actually I want if it does not contain with in single page, it will continue in another page. I am giving some code bellow which I have written in my project. It works for single page but not multipage.

```
CGContextRef pdfContext;
CFStringRef path;
CFURLRef url;
CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = NULL;
path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, [filename UTF8String],
                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path,
                                     kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
CFRelease (path);
myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,
                                         &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                         &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, CFSTR("MyApp Proposal"));
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("MyApp for iPad"));
pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url, &pageRect, myDictionary);

CFRelease(myDictionary);
CFRelease(url);

float originX = 20;

float originY = 40;

CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Helvetica", 14, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);

NSString *contractText= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"contract"];

UIColor *colorContractText = [UIColor blackColor];

if(contractText != nil)
{
  CGSize contractSize = [contractText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(580, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

  [contractText drawInRect:CGRectMake(originX, originY, contractSize.width, contractSize.height) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:colorContractText}];

}
```

I will be grateful if some one help me. I am waiting for response.